# Can I track grants against contributions?

Tags: civicontribute, financial-types, civigrant

Is there a way with CiviGrant to match money received as Contributions with money disbursed?

E.g. if I receive a donation for $100K for a scholarship fund, and I give out 3 scholarships of $20K each, is there a report that can show me that I have $40K left in the fund?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CiviGrant is not sync'd with CiviContribute in current CiviCRM version. You will need to build an entity that will link CiviGrant with CiviContribute or use Financial Accounts(linked with Financial type).

This look like nice feature. I am happy to build an extension for this if you willing to sponsor.

Answer (score 2):

To meet this need, I commissioned the [Grant Financial Support](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.grantfinancialsupport) extension, which fills an important piece of this need.  It's not complete in and of itself, but enables accounting integration for grants.  I have a second extension that links grants to financial types with the help of this first extension, but it's not stable enough for release yet.